# Straight Line Equation between two points

Tags: line, paint, points

I need to paint the line which links two points.

I am doing it, in Java. I receive two points as parameters and I have to calculate if the straight line between them, is inside the black figure.

I developed my own solution using the straight line equation, but my results are different than using the "professional" programs (such as GIMP or even MS Paint).

Here is a example of what I want:

[alt text http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/788/img1q.png](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/788/img1q.png)

But my algorithm does this:

[alt text http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/1908/img2d.png](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/1908/img2d.png)

*The green point is out of the figure and this is not possible.

Any ideas? Anyone know which code is been using for this, in "professional" apps?

Thanks!
Daniel.

EDIT: Images

Comment: Daniel. This question can't really be answered. You haven't given us enough information, and this question will probably be closed. To stop this happening can you edit your question and tell us what technology you're using (operating system and development tools), and tell us *exactly* what you're trying to achive (e.g. how do you define the line to be drawn? as a list of points?)

Comment: Also, what algorithm are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are truncating instead of rounding to the nearest pixel. Difficult to see on those small black ink splotches. Could you post the code?

Comment: Indeed. Looks like your algorithm expects there to be 2 line segments instead of 3 segments. Is your dx/dy right? (Given that you round, not truncate).

Comment: WOW! Peter you are a genius!!!

I was using integers and that was the problem!

Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 3):

"Professional" programs most likely use [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenhams_line_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Straignt lines are drawn using Bresenham's algorithm usually. I didn't get your point about green point being out of the figure - there's clipping to not waste time drawing outside the visible area.